# Change bg (css) automatically using JS (and a slowly transition)

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, getelementbyid, smoothing

I have a div (one of my carousel's items) with an inline style that inputs a .jpg as a bg img. I want to change that bg to another one in 3 seconds, automatically, than maintain the second one. The thing is, with the code I already have, I can change the bg, but I have no idea on how to create a smooth transition using the getElementById followed by style. I tried css3, but IE doesn't show the effect. This is my js:

```
<script>
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000,
    cycle: true
  });

  function show_banner(){

  document.getElementById('mainImage').style.backgroundImage="url('images/slider/bg1.jpg')";

  }

  setTimeout(show_banner, 500);

</script>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="mainImage" class="item active" data-interval="9000"  style="background: url(images/slider/bg0.jpg)">
```

I know that my code is a mess. I would also ask you guys to show me a better way to organize it.

P.S.: you may ask why I'm using a data-interval if I'm already setting an interval (3000) in the js. I just can't make the interval work if I don't set both numbers. I ended up with a not so satisfying result :/

I'll appreciate all the support! Thank you!

Comment: you dont want to use jQuery? If yes then when you are setting new image set start animation on its transparency to have changing effect.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I read about the .animate and it seems like I can't use background-image with it. I managed to get the effect with this:

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#mainImage').fadeOut('slow', function () {

      $('#mainImage').css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/slider/bg1.jpg)' });

      $('#mainImage').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });

But I am getting a "white flash" in between the two images. Do you any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to transition smoothly from one `background-image` to another is to position a transparent `::after` pseudo-element squarely over the top of the original element.

Then, when a javascript updates the `classList` of the original element, the opacity of the `::after` pseudo-element can transition smoothly from fully transparent to fully opaque.

See the example below:

```js
function newBackground() {
 var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
    setTimeout(function(){
     mainImage.classList.add('showNewBackground');}, 
 3000);
}

window.addEventListener('load',newBackground,false);
```

```css
div {
position: relative;
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
}

div::after {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
background: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
opacity: 0;
transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

div.showNewBackground::after {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainImage" style="background: url('data:image/png;base64,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');">
</div>
```

**N.B.** Pay no special attention to the `base-64` images in the example - I've only included them to demonstrate the effect. You can replace each of these images with your own images.

Comment: Hello Rounin! Thank you for the support. Unfortunately I couldn't create the effect using your example. I am sure I did something wrong, but just couldn't find the error. I managed to create the effect using this:

$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mainImage').fadeOut('slow', function () {

                $('#mainImage').css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/slider/bg1.jpg)' });

                $('#mainImage').fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });

But I am getting a "white flash" in between the two images. Do you any idea why?

Comment: I am not familar with jQuery. The javascript above should work just fine. All you need to do is replace background: `url('data:image/png;base64,ivBORblahblahblahblahblah=');` with `background: url('images/slider/bg1.jpg');` - please try that and let me know if it's still not working.

Comment: Sorry, man! I was doing something wrong. It is working! Thank you!

Comment: Is it difficult to toggle these two images through time? Instead of changing once and keeping the second one, change once and then show again the first one.

Comment: Not difficult, no. For a single change (as above) you would use the `setTimeout` function. For two changes (forwards and then backwards) you would probably use the `setTimeout` function twice. If you want to keep cycling through the alternate changes, you would use the `setInterval` function.